# Style a PHP "thank you" message so it shows up on same page towards the bottom

Tags: php, html, forms, echo, phpmailer

I've been trying to style a **"thank you"** message when users submit their email on the same page, so that the message shows up underneath the submit form in a color of my choosing.

> However, so far my code only submits the email without a thank you
>   message, it doesnt seem to echo the p tag with an id of feedback.

**So how can I fix my code to make the p-tag with an id of #feedback appear as the thank you message when an email is submitted?**

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

require("C:/inetpub/folder/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.comcast.net"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = "username@comcast.net"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "**********"; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';// Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;                                   
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->setFrom('$email', 'Guest');
$mail->addAddress('admin@mydomain.com', 'Support');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "A new member wishes to be added";
$mail->Body = $email;
$mail->AltBody = $email;


$mail2 = new PHPMailer();
$mail2->IsSMTP();
$mail2->Host = "smtp.comcast.net"; 
$mail2->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail2->Username = "username@comcast.net"; // SMTP username
$mail2->Password = "*********"; // SMTP password
$mail2->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                           
$mail2->Port = 25;                                 
$mail2->setFrom('support@mydomain.com', 'Support');
$mail2->AddAddress("$email");
$mail2->addReplyTo('support@mydomain.com');
$mail2->WordWrap = 50;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$mail2->Subject = "Thanks for signing up";
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['admin@mydomain.com']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['loo@mydomain.com']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


$message = '<html><body>';
$mail2->IsHTML(true);
$message .= '<p style="font-size:16px; color:#000; font-weight:bold;">Welcome,</p> ';
$message .= "<p style='line-height:1.6; color:#666; font-size:16px;'>You have been added to.</p> " ;
$message .= "</body></html>";
$mail2->Body = $message;
$mail2->AltBody = $message;

if (!$mail2->Send()) {

$feedback = 'Thanks for the email';

}
if (!$mail->Send()) {

$feedback = 'Thanks for the email';

}

?>
```

**The html:**

```
<div class="guestlist">
<form action="?" method="post">
<input type="email" title="Enter Email Address" class="emailaddress" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" />
<button class="button" title="Submit Email to Guestlist"  name="submit" value="Submit" type='submit'>Join</button>
 <p id="feedback"> <?php echo $feedback; ?> </p>
  </form>
  </div>   
  </div>
```

Comment: How is the HTML related to the php?

Comment: The feedback id with the php echo feedback command

Answer (score 0):

You should read PHP manual for basic understanding of how the code gets interpreted and compiled and what's sent as the output.

1. The user sees the html with `feedback` variable being empty first;
2. The user clicks the button, stuff is sent to the server. The `feedback` variable now holds a value, but the HTML page doesn't reload, so it stays the same.

Either reload the HTML page sending `feedback` there or use ajax and listen for the answer:

```
$("button[name=submit]").on("click",function(){
    type: "post",
    url: mail.php,
    success: function(serverResponse){
        $("#feedback").html(serverResponse);
    }
});
```

in this case you should `echo $feedback;`

Comment: I prefer to do this without loading another html page or using ajax, I was following this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6q7ndD0rt2s  but I was unable to intergrate it to my code

Comment: @user3771570 you need to read the PHP manual starting with the very basics... Then you might understand why PHP code being server-sided can't dynamically change the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how $feedback would ever be set if the email was successful.

```
if (!$mail2->Send()) {

$feedback = 'Thanks for the email';

}
if (!$mail->Send()) {

$feedback = 'Thanks for the email';

}
```

To me that says if not successful.

Comment: Plus why set $feedback on a success and not display an appropriate message for when the email is not sent correctly.  And why define it twice.

Comment: Haha...no joke.  I wrote my mailer function like years ago based off http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp.  Only issues I've had have been with AIM because they're persnickety about their mailing headers and if you miss an EOL char, you're hosed and it never gets past their spam filter.  I digress though.

Comment: I had this before if(!$mail->Send()) {echo "Message could not be sent<p>"; echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; exit"}

Comment: And whenever I loaded my webpage I would get an error message instead of my site, so I'm sure there's something wrong with that code. Also btw my page contains PHP and HTML, but is saved as a .php

Comment: Well yea, it should be .php to run php code, and having both in one file is not the issue.  With the above code your echo statement with Mailer Error doesn't make much sense to me.  There's exit" which " would cause a syntax error I'm guessing and http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php says exit stops running the rest of the script so I don't see why that's there.  Just take a step back, breath, and echo simpler things while learning and read up on the docs.  I'm not trying to be harsh, but there's a lot of documentation and you should really focus on getting the basics down.